# Why does my button not trigger the timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, button

I found a very simple Javascript example to learn how time trackers work. I am comparing the code since hours, and I don't get it running. The update of the clock is working, but the button does not trigger the time tracker.

Where is my error?

Below is the sample JS code.  The clock updates periodically according to the defined "setInterval()". I only cannot find the error to trigger start of the clock as soon as the button is pressed.

```js
$(function() {
  registerClock();
  setTime();
});

var currentdate;
var stopWatchRunning = false;
var startTime;

function registerClock() {
  setInterval(updateClock, 250);
}

function updateClock() {
  setTime();
  setStopWatch();
}



function setTime() {
  currentdate = new Date();
  var datetime = +currentdate.getDate() + "." +
    (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "." +
    currentdate.getFullYear() + " " +
    currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
    currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" +
    currentdate.getSeconds();
  $("#time").text(datetime);
}


$("#startstop").click(function() {
  if (stopWatchRunning == false) {
    startTime = new Date();
    stopWatchRunning = true;
  } else {
    stopWatchRunning = false;
  }
});


function setStopWatch() {
  if (stopWatchRunning == false) {
    return;
  }
  var timeElapsed = currentdate - startTime;
  var duration = new Date(timeElapsed);
  var showDuration = duration.getHours() - 1 + ":" +
    duration.getMinutes() + ":" +
    duration.getSeconds();
  $("#tracker").text(showDuration);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/timer_neu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stoppuhr</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h1>Uhrzeit</h1>
    <h1 id="time">19:53:00</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h1>Stoppuhr</h1>
    <h1 id="tracker">00:00:00</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p><button id="startstop" class="btn btn-default">Start/Stop</button></p>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: any messages/errors/warning in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: It does start recording as soon as i press the button, just that it is in a weird format like `1:0:4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the $("#startstop") click function inside the document ready function as below

```
$(function() {
  registerClock();
  setTime();

  $("#startstop").click(function() {
    //alert('change')
  if (stopWatchRunning == false) {
      startTime = new Date();
      stopWatchRunning = true;
    } else {
      stopWatchRunning = false;
    }
  });
});
```